# Correct way to store an array of custom objects in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store a custom object `Event` in firebase, an `Event` can have several `StopOff` and `User`, I am holding them in the `Event` object as `[StopOff]` and `[User]`

However when I attempt to save to firebase, it gives me the issue that these types are not the base savable types supported in Firebase.

This is ok for single objects as I can use a `toAnyObject` method that maps them down into base key and values, however with the arrays I cant see a way to achieve this for each item in the array?

This gets worse whem these arrays of custom models also have further custom objects in them creating a tree

Here is the method I have the issue with

```
    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
    return [
        "name": name,
        "users": users,
        "startPoint": startPoint.toAnyObject(),
        "endPoint": endPoint.toAnyObject(),
        "stopOffs": stopOffs
    ]
}
```

I am sure my approach must just be incorrect as i am used to traditional SQL backends, but would apprciate my approach being corrected

Comment: Are you using firestore or real-time database?

Comment: firestore i believe

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way and are going to code yourself into a corner. Firestore stores *strings, booleans, numbers, dates, null, and nested arrays and objects* but note that for objects: *This isn't supported in Swift. Use a value type instead.*. So. Don't store objects. Store the base data types only. You should really study up on document based NoSQL as it's quote a leap from SQL and requires a different thought process when approaching data. You could consider a 'document' and object with it's fields being properties, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this, is there any good guides in the correct approach / can you suggest the implimentation of this model that would be more suited? I’m struggling to find tutorials around using more than base types when a model must contain a relationship other models

Comment: Todd put together a [great series on Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) and it covers database architecture in depth in eposides [#3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7d5Zeic63s) and [#4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo).

Comment: Great thanks for this I’ll give it a watch

Comment: I would guess that  your Event Object would be 'mapped' to a document. Inside the document you will have fields, event_name, event_date etc. I don't know what Stopoff is but I would guess its also a group of more primative types. So you would create a collection within the Event document to store Stopoff and User data. OR you may want to have a separate collection of Stopoff documents a User collection to store user documents and within your Event document, keep a reference to those. Just depends on the use case.

Comment: great thanks for all your help with this, thats greatly improved my understanding!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using

`"users": users.map { $0.toAnyObject() }`

inside my parent `toAnyObject` function, allows conversion of the array into objects as expected and stores within cloud store, hopefully this is the best solution